# Dayofweek Yii2 activequery

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I need to know how the following query can be written as a Yii2 ActiveQuery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM planner 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET (DAYOFWEEK(:day), days)
```

Hope someone can help or has a better idea to achieve to same.

Comment: I'm sorry, the subquery isn't necessary. I edited my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this `ActiveQuery` code.

```
ModelName::find()->where('FIND_IN_SET (DAYOFWEEK(:day), days)', [':day' => 'value'])->all();
```

Comment: This is what I need! Thank you!